# PyCharm のコンソールでプロンプトの表示が変わってしまうのはなぜですか？

Tags: python, pycharm, console

PyCharmを使用しているのですが、コンソールに、

```
>>>
```

と出てくるときと、

```
In[2]:
```

と出てくるときの違いは何でしょうか？
インタープリタの設定をいじっていると時々変わってしまうのですが、意味が分かっていません。
初歩的な質問で申し訳ありませんがご教示いただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

何かしらの操作で[ipython -PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/ipython/) が起動されているのでしょう。

`>>>`はPythonのインタープリターシェルのプロンプトで、`In[2]:`とか`Out[3]:`とかはipythonの表示です。

例えばPyCharmのこちらのヘルプ記事とかを参考にしてみてください。
[Python コンソール](https://pleiades.io/help/pycharm/interactive-console.html)
[IPython マジックコマンド](https://pleiades.io/help/pycharm/ipython.html)